# "Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" on delete event

Tags: mysql, timeout

I'm trying to delete a row in my table

```
delete from tbllink where linkid=243
```

but i keep getting that error message:

> Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting
>   transaction

As mentioned in other questions, I tried running :

```
show open tables where in_use>0;
```

This returned 0 results. I also tried running:

```
show processlist
```

This returned these columns:

```
> 2244  username IP:50487   newdatabasetemp Sleep   1777        
> 2247  username IP:50723   newdatabasetemp Sleep   1346        
> 2249  username IP:50725   newdatabasetemp Sleep   1285
```

I tried reconnecting to the server but still the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Few points to consider :

1. innodb_buffer_pool_size should be set to about 70% of available RAM.
2. You can execute :

   SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000;

And then this:

```
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000;
```

3. Can you kill all the processes related to mysql and restart the server and try again?

Answer (score 4):

I was getting same error when I was deleting all records from a table.

Except me nobody was using server so I went ahead killed all running processes one by one using `kill <process id>` and it worked.