# Updating the count each time a variable appears in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table called staysafe with the following columns:

id | email | orders

The id and email columns have been populated.

I then want to go through the Wordpress postmeta table and count each time the email address appears in the row where "_billing_email" appears for the meta_key, then update the staysafe table with how many times each email address appeared.

The postmeta table is set out as:

meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value

I'm using the following but keep getting a runtime error (the postmeta table is big!!), where am I going wrong?

```
update staysafe

set orders =
(select count(*) 
from wp_postmeta
where email = meta_value)
```

Comment: Please tag a DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, etc); that way, the question will be visible to people who are knowledgeable in your specific SQL dialect. Also, please include exactly what error you're getting.

Comment: @JoshEller Sorry updated now, I'm getting a runtime error as the table is so big. It hasn't factored in the "_billing_email" in my attempt so may be that would help???

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want this:

```
update staysafe s
set s.orders = (
  select count(*) 
  from wp_postmeta
  where meta_key = '_billing_email' and meta_value = s.email
)
```

This will update all the rows of the table `staysafe`.
If you want to update a specific row then add a WHERE clause:

```
where s.email = 'someemail@aaa.com'
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it'd work but I keep hitting a timeout, is there a way around it?

'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Error code 1205.'

Comment: A composite index on (meta_key, meta_value) in the table wp_postmeta would help to speed up the process. For the timeout error that you get there are several questions/answers here in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547173/error-code-1205-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-on-de and others.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate and `join`:

```
update staysafe s left join
       (select meta_value, count(*) as cnt
        from wp_postmeta
        where meta_key = '_billing_email'
        group by metavalue
       ) pm
       on s.email = pm.email
    set orders = coalesce(cnt, 0);
```

If you don't care about `0` values, then change the `left join` to an `inner join`.